# UPDATE query with values from SELECT subquery, efficiently

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I tried to come up with a query that updates records in a MySQL table using other records in the same table, but I had mixed results between local testing and production. I don't know much about subqueries, so I want to bring this question here. In local development with MySQL InnoDB 5.6.23, a query on a dataset of about 180k records take 25 to 30 seconds. On a staging server with MySQL InnoDB 5.5.32 and a dataset of 254k records, the query seems to stall for hours until it's stopped, taking 100% of a CPU core.

This is the query I came up with:

```
UPDATE
    `product_lang` AS `pl1`
SET
    pl1.`name` = (
        SELECT pl2.`name` FROM (SELECT `name`, `id_product`, `id_lang` FROM `product_lang`) AS `pl2`
        WHERE pl1.`id_product` = pl2.`id_product`
        AND pl2.`id_lang` = 1
    )
WHERE
    pl1.`id_lang` != 1
```

The objective is to replace the value of `name` in product records where `id_lang` is not 1 (default language for the sake of explaining) with the value of `name` of records value with the default `id_lang` of 1.

I know that subqueries are inefficient, but I really don't know how to solve this problem, and it would be a great plus to leave this in SQL-land instead of using the app layer to do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write the query like this:

```
UPDATE product_lang pl1
    SET pl1.name = (SELECT pl2.`name`
                    FROM (SELECT `name`, `id_product`, `id_lang`
                          FROM `product_lang`
                         ) `pl2`
                    WHERE pl1.`id_product` = pl2.`id_product` AND pl2.`id_lang` = 1
                   )
WHERE pl1.`id_lang` <> 1
```

Then you have a problem.  The only index that can help is on `product_lang(id_lang)`.

I would recommend writing this as a `join`:

```
UPDATE product_lang pl1 join
       (select id_product, pl.name
        from product_lang
        where id_lang = 1
       ) pl2
       on pl1.id_lang <> 1 and pl2.id_product = pl1.id_product
    SET pl1.name =  pl2.name
WHERE pl1.id_lang <> 1
```

The index that you want for this query is `product_lang(id_lang, id_product)` and `product_lang(id_product)`.  However, this seems like a strange `update`, because it will set all the names to the name from language 1.

Comment: The query needs to reset all the languages to the default one for each product. That's why it's weird! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE product_lang AS pl1
  JOIN product_lang AS pl2
      ON pl1.`id_product` =
         pl2.`id_product`
  SET pl1.name = pl2.name
  WHERE pl2.`id_lang`  = 1
    AND pl1.`id_lang` != 1;
```

And have `INDEX(id_lang, id_product)`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is an index specifying columns id _ product and id_lang.

Answer (score 0):

update pl1
set pl1.name=pl2.name
from product_lang pl1
,`product_lang` pl2
where pl1.`id_product` = pl2.`id_product` AND pl2.`id_lang` = 1
and pl1.`id_lang` <> 1

The composit index that will be required will be  id_product and id_lang  for